# How to call JavaScript function on click of menu URL link of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How to call JavaScript function on click of menu URL link of WordPress?
I have tried

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".menu-item-2916").on("click", function(){ 
getServerPath('signin.html?reqType=login');
 });
});
```

which is not working for me. This menu is LOGIN menu for my website.

Comment: #menu-item-num, this is not correct might be check with correct id

Comment: Put you code under dom ready event.

Comment: I have put my exact code above. If i remove # from URL section in menu i cant click on link.

Comment: we checking on it but need more information. What you need on click? need to open next tab or same link replace with this or join at the end.

Comment: Just replaced .menu-item-2916 with #menu-item-2916 and it worked. Thankyou all.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".nav li.menu-item-2916").on("click", function(){ 
getServerPath('signin.html?reqType=login');
 });
});
```

Comment: What you want to exactly here??

Comment: Just replaced .menu-item-2916 with #menu-item-2916 and it worked.

Comment: my code it's worked after replaced .menu-item-2916 with #menu-item-2916 ??

Answer (score 0):

you have not clarify whats you need exact. but try this one if you need to change with this url on click.

> ## menu-item-24  replace your menu id

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("nav li#menu-item-24").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.open('/signin.html?reqType=login','_self');
            return false;
        });
    });
```